# Declaring an array at object instantiation in C++

Tags: c++, arrays

I'm trying to make a TiledMap class that hold an array of ints to represent the tiles. The dimensions of the tiled maps need to be anything I want, but I'm looking for a way around declaring a large array in the fields and then treating it like a smaller array with the actual desired dimensions.

So instead of this

```
class TiledMap{
private:
    int mapArray[100][100];// actual dimensions would be smaller than 100
    char width, height;
public:
    void setDimensions(char width, char height);
    //...
}
```

I would like the array to be declared on creation of the object. Logically this should work since you would have the size of the array when it allocates memory, but the only way I can think of doing it is making five thousand objects to represent the possible dimensions in a [100][100] array with their respective arrays declared in respective headers (TiledMap1010,TiledMap1011,TiledMap1012, etc.)

If anyone knows of some clever way to do this cleanly I'd love to see it. Thanks so much.

Comment: Use a vector of vectors.

Comment: This is a very common problem and the common solution is to use [`std::vector`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector).

Comment: `class TiledMap { std::vector< std::vector<int>> _mapVec; public: setDimensions(size_type width, size_type height) { _mapVec.resize(width); for(auto& row : _mapVec) row.resize(height); } };`

Comment: @George thank you!

Comment: if you wan't the "array to be declared on creation of the object", you should pass the dimensions on the constructor.

Comment: @EduardoPascualAseff So the problem with that is I wouldn't be able to create the array as a field. It would just be a local variable in the constructor. You'd nee to somehow pass the dimensions before it began to allocate memory for the object. You do have the info before memory allocation, it's just that there's no feasible way to get it there.